Characterization of self-conjugate spin$^c$ structures
Let $M$ be an oriented Riemannian $n$-manifold. Then we can choose a trivializing open cover $M=\bigcup_\alpha  U_\alpha$ for $TM$ and corresponding transition functions $g_{\alpha \beta}:U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to \text{SO}(n)$. A spin structure on $M$ is a lift $\tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to \text{Spin}(n)$ satisfying the coycle condition $\tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}\tilde{g}_{\beta\gamma}=\tilde{g}_{\alpha\gamma}$. A spin$^c$ structure on $M$ is defined similarly. Since $\text{Spin}^c(n)=(\text{Spin}(n)\times S^1)/\{(\pm 1, \pm 1)\}$, there is a natural map $\text{Spin}(n)\to \text{Spin}^c(n)$, and therefore a spin structure canonically induces a spin$^c$ structure. On the other hand, there is a conjugation map (or involution) $\text{Spin}^c(n)\to \text{Spin}^c(n)$ given by complex conjugation on the $S^1$ factor.
Now suppose $M$ has a spin structure (and hence a spin$^c$ structure). Let $\text{Spin}(M)$ (resp. $\text{Spin}^c(M)$) denote the equivalence classes of all spin (resp. spin$^c$) structures on $M$. By above there is a conjugation map $\text{Spin}^c(M)\to \text{Spin}^c(M)$, and clearly $\text{Spin}(M)$ is invariant under conjugation. However, a self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure is not necessarily induced by a spin structure. Note that $\text{Spin}(M)$ and $\text{Spin}^c(M)$ are in 1-1 correspondence with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)$ and $H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$, respectively. The map $\text{Spin}(M)\to \text{Spin}^c(M)$ corresponds to the Bockstein homomorphism $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4942658/can-two-different-spin-structures-on-a-manifold-induce-the-same-spinc-structu). Is there a characterization of conjugation $\text{Spin}^c(M)\to \text{Spin}^c(M)$ and self-conjugate spin$^c$ structures in terms of cohomology, etc.?

$\newcommand{\Spin}{\mathrm{Spin}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Here's one way to think about the data of
(self-conjugate) spin$^c$ structures. A spin$^c$ structure has the associated data of a class $c_1\in H^2(M;\Z)$
with $c_1\bmod 2 = w_2(M)$, defining a map of sets $c_1\colon \Spin^c(M)\to H^2(M;\Z)$. To make contact with the
cohomological description of $\Spin^c(M)$ let $x\in H^2(M;\Z)$ act on $H^2(M;\Z)$ by $y\mapsto y+2x$; then the map
$c_1\colon\Spin^c(M)\to H^2(M;\Z)$ is $H^2(M;\Z)$-equivariant.
Complex conjugation acts on $\Spin^c(M)$ as you described above, and acts on $H^2(M;\Z)$ by $-1$; the map $c_1$
above is equivariant for complex conjugation. Moreover, the $H^2(M;\Z)$-actions on $\Spin^c(M)$ and $H^2(M;\Z)$ are
compatible with conjugation: if $\mathfrak s\in\Spin^c(M)$ and $x\in H^2(M;\Z)$, then $\overline{x\cdot\mathfrak s}
= (-x)\cdot\overline{\mathfrak s}$.
A self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure $\mathfrak s$ is a fixed point of conjugation on $\Spin^c(M)$. Since all of the
data above is conjugation-equivariant, nice things happen when we take fixed points.

The $H^2(M;\Z)$-action on $\Spin^c(M)$ restricts to an action of the conjugation-fixed points of $H^2(M;\Z)$ on
the conjugation-fixed points of $\Spin^c(M)$. This in particular gives an action of $H^1(M;\Z/2)$ on the set of
self-conjugate spin$^c$ structures, as the image of the Bockstein $H^1(M;\Z/2)\to H^2(M;\Z)$ is precisely the
$2$-torsion subgroup of $H^2(M;\Z)$, which is precisely the solutions to $x = -x$, i.e. the fixed points of the
inversion action.

Because the map $c_1$ is equivariant, it induces a map on fixed points: a self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure has
an associated class in the inversion-fixed points of $H^2(M;\Z)$. It would be nice to pull back across the
Bockstein to $H^1(M;\Z/2)$, but if the Bockstein is noninjective there could be ambiguity in this choice. To fix
this, redefine a self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure as a spin$^c$ structure $\mathfrak s$ together with a chosen
isomorphism $f\colon \mathfrak s\overset{\cong}{\to} \overline{\mathfrak s}$. Two isomorphisms are the same if they
belong to the same path component of the space of isomorphisms $\mathfrak s\overset{\cong}{\to}\overline{\mathfrak
s}$.


Specifying this data is equivalent to specifying a preimage of $c_1(\mathfrak s)$ in $H^1(M;\Z/2)$. One way to see
this is to represent $H^2(M;\Z)$ as isomorphism classes of complex line bundles on $M$, and $H^1(M;\Z/2)$ as
isomorphism classes of real line bundles on $M$; the data of $f$ uplifts us from “the line bundle $L$ classified
by $c_1(\mathfrak s)$ is isomorphic to its conjugate” to “here is an isomorphism from $L$ to $\overline L$,” and
the fixed points of that isomorphism are the real line bundle whose class in $H^1(M;\Z/2)$ is the desired preimage
of $c_1(\mathfrak s)$.
The map from self-conjugate spin$^c$ structures to $H^1(M;\Z/2)$ is equivariant for the $H^1(M;\Z/2)$-action, but
$H^1(M;\Z/2)$ acting on itself by $(x,y)\mapsto 2x+y$ is the trivial action. Thus all self-conjugate spin$^c$
structures in a given $H^1(M;\Z/2)$-orbit have the same associated class in $H^1(M;\Z/2)$.
So, to summarize, if we include the data of the isomorphism $\mathfrak s\overset{\cong}{\to}\overline{\mathfrak s}$
in the definition of a self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure, we discover that:

A self-conjugate spin$^c$ structure $\mathfrak s$ gives rise to a class $w_1\in H^1(M;\Z/2)$ with
$\beta(w_1(\mathfrak s)) = w_2(M)$, and
the set of self-conjugate spin$^c$ structures with given $w_1$ is acted on by $H^1(M;\Z/2)$. (In fact, one can
show this set is in non-natural bijection with $H^1(M;\Z/2)$, just like general spin$^c$ structures and
$H^2(M;\Z)$.)

